# Append wearable APK file to handheld APK file using Eclipse

Tags: android, wear-os

Does somebody know a solution how can I build APK file using Eclipse or manually for both handheld and wearable usage? As I know Android Studio gradle script copies apk into raw folder. Is it enough? Are there the other rules for such build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tangtungai/how-to-develop-and-package-android-wear-app-using-eclipse-ef1b34126a5d) with steps on how to setup and package an Android Wear app using Eclipse.

Prerequisites:

- Make sure that you already have Eclipse setup with the latest ADT (Android Development Tools). If not, you can find the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).
- Download the latest Android SDK.
- Add Android Wear Support library (`android.support.wearable`) to your workspace. Go to your Android SDK folder, and find this file, `./extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/support/wearable/1.0.0/wearable-1.0.0.aar`. Copy the `wearable-1.0.0.aar` to a new location that you preferred. Then rename it to zip file before extracting it. After you extract it, create a `libs` folder and copy classes.jar into the `libs` folder.
- Add this Android Wear Support library to your Eclipse workspace.

**To package your app, follow these steps:**

- Open your WearApp AndroidManifest.xml file and pay attention to the Version Code and Version Name.
- Create a new Project (WearAppOnPhone) for your Android app that will be installed on your phone. Please make sure the package name should be the same as your Android Wear app.
- Import/Add [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install) to this project.
- Open back your WearApp project and generate the signed APK file and rename it to `wearable_app.apk`.
- Copy this file and put it into your WearAppOnPhone project at folder `/WearAppOnPhone/res/raw/`.
- On DemoWearAppOnPhone project, create a new xml file, `wearable_app_desc.xml` at `res/xml/ folder`.
- Open the AndroidManifest.xml file for WearAppOnPhone project.
- Add in the 2 extra meta-data block. No changes required.

  `<meta-data android:name="package name"`
  `android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>`

  `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"`
  `android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>`
- Double check your WearAppOnPhone project structure. It should be like this:

[image: screenshote]

- Finally, generate a signed APK for WearAppOnPhone and you are ready to release your first Android Wear app.

Hope this helps!